# Is there a way to get Keyboard change reflect on Appimage?

Tags: linux, keyboard, inkscape, appimage

I am using ibus keyboard layout and I can change the language globally, However this change is not reflected on Appimages (I am using Inkscape). Is there a solution to this problem or are Appimages supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be addressed by the Inskape AppImage authors. They are the ones who decide whether the bundle will use the system settings or a fixed language/keyboard preferences.